# Sorting out duplicates in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a website with a database over different phones. And to gather data from the database, I have this code

```
//echo "SELECT * FROM `product_info` DESC";die;
    $filter = $this->queries->custom("SELECT * FROM `product_info`GROUP BY 'model' ORDER BY  `model` ASC");
```

When I use this code now, it only shows one model, instead of all the different models.

Since i've added some of the models more than once i Would like to sort those out.

Like, i have fx added the iPhone 7 5 different times in my database and of course i wouldn't want the site to show it 5 times, therefore i would like to sort after models and only show each model one time.
I've read about the array_unique, but didn't quite understand it.

Comment: best way to do it is it by filtering the query. Add select distinct model from product_info. Simple, clear, efficent

Comment: How does your data in the table look? Is it possible that all of your phones have the same value for `model`?

Comment: no, the value for model changes for each phone, that's why it's the best sorting option, if I could avoid duplicates.
Model columns are filled with the model of the phones like: Galaxy S7, iPhone 7, iPhone SE, Honor 8 and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the problem, it's a little typo. You used single quotes ( ' ) instead of backticks ( ` ) for your `GROUP BY` column. Single quotes are for string values. This means that your current query groups by the string "model" (and not by the column `model`), which is of course the same string for every record.

So either use backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_info` GROUP BY `model` ORDER BY `model` ASC
```

or omit the backticks at all because they are only necessary when your column is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html):

```
SELECT * FROM product_info GROUP BY model ORDER BY model ASC
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the DISTINCT keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `product_info`GROUP BY 'model' ORDER BY  `model` ASC
```

Comment: I've tried that already, but it stil just returns one phone. If I remove the "GROUP BY 'model" part, it shows more phones, but duplicates aswell...

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ON (column_name) - did you try this approach?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ON` is PostgreSQL syntax, not MySQL.

Comment: You mean like SELECT DISTINCT 'model' FROM `product_info`GROUP BY 'model' ORDER BY  `model` ASC?

No results at all then..

Comment: @MikkelSønderskovSørensen remove GROUP BY 'model'

Comment: I get an error because the site needs the rest of the data from the other columns in 'product_info' and without those there arent any results at all..

Comment: @MikkelSønderskovSørensen select * from product_info group by model . This is the query. If you want to put the values in an array reply this comment and i will show you

Comment: It still just shows the first phone thats in the database unfortunately.